# Refresh cache on App update not working - Vue, webpack, router split code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, caching, webpack, deployment

I apply [lazy loading and code splitting](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html) in my vue app

But somehow when I update my code and I deploy it to production only some chunks are updated with a new hash.

```
 File                                      Size             Gzipped

  dist/js/chunk-vendors.8bacd999.js         1379.15 KiB      418.03 KiB
  dist/js/super-user.55f6d84e.js            230.82 KiB       43.40 KiB
  dist/js/user.75857fc3.js                  141.31 KiB       28.63 KiB
  dist/js/worker.3f845d96.js                116.95 KiB       27.14 KiB
  dist/js/super-user~user~worker.89497bd    95.72 KiB        26.28 KiB
  4.js
  dist/js/super-user~worker.de7f3513.js     41.93 KiB        14.24 KiB
  dist/js/app.d05288d8.js                   33.93 KiB        9.72 KiB
  dist/js/landing-page.abe82391.js          28.14 KiB        10.78 KiB
  dist/precache-manifest.9e6d4f8b3b203e5    6.23 KiB         1.84 KiB
  a7409c4e5738c04b0.js
  dist/service-worker.js                    1.04 KiB         0.61 KiB
  dist/css/chunk-vendors.c380a352.css       354.50 KiB       40.53 KiB
  dist/css/super-user~user~worker.b6103c    30.99 KiB        4.90 KiB
  9d.css
  dist/css/user.efb5b1bf.css                24.94 KiB        4.66 KiB
  dist/css/super-user.78d831e9.css          17.71 KiB        3.26 KiB
  dist/css/super-user~worker.3a0fff16.cs    12.84 KiB        1.87 KiB
  s
  dist/css/landing-page.de5bd5da.css        7.32 KiB         1.77 KiB
  dist/css/worker.7dcd23eb.css              5.72 KiB         1.63 KiB
  dist/css/app.3e078b33.css                 3.55 KiB         1.16 KiB
```

**VS**

```
  File                                      Size             Gzipped

  dist/js/chunk-vendors.8bacd999.js         1379.15 KiB      418.03 KiB
  dist/js/super-user.0cf42025.js            233.18 KiB       43.64 KiB
  dist/js/user.75857fc3.js                  141.31 KiB       28.63 KiB
  dist/js/worker.3f845d96.js                116.95 KiB       27.14 KiB
  dist/js/super-user~user~worker.89497bd    95.72 KiB        26.28 KiB
  4.js
  dist/js/super-user~worker.de7f3513.js     41.93 KiB        14.24 KiB
  dist/js/app.68802416.js                   33.93 KiB        9.72 KiB
  dist/js/landing-page.abe82391.js          28.14 KiB        10.78 KiB
  dist/precache-manifest.5d1728ab9e82dbe    6.23 KiB         1.84 KiB
  f01c617532cf35342.js
  dist/service-worker.js                    1.04 KiB         0.61 KiB
  dist/css/chunk-vendors.c380a352.css       354.50 KiB       40.53 KiB
  dist/css/super-user~user~worker.b6103c    30.99 KiB        4.90 KiB
  9d.css
  dist/css/user.efb5b1bf.css                24.94 KiB        4.66 KiB
  dist/css/super-user.822e51f6.css          17.71 KiB        3.26 KiB
  dist/css/super-user~worker.3a0fff16.cs    12.84 KiB        1.87 KiB
  s
  dist/css/landing-page.de5bd5da.css        7.32 KiB         1.77 KiB
  dist/css/worker.7dcd23eb.css              5.72 KiB         1.63 KiB
  dist/css/app.3e078b33.css                 3.55 KiB         1.16 KiB
```

I've updated a view, we will call it Feature.vue, and is defined as

```
const Feature = () =>
  import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ "./views/Feature.vue");
```

But in the build the hash of the user modules are not updated, this causes to a lot of users see old versions of my app and need to go to the landing page and make a refresh to refresh the app, if they refresh the page on feature they can see changes, but the next time they access to feature the cache will show the old version.

Also to be more specific my changes are some js changes, then at least the js file needs to change the hash **there is a way to force change hash of all files every update?**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assuming you have a Vue CLI project. under your `src` folder open up `registerServiceWorker.js` and make sure to flush the cache when the service worker detects changes:

```js
import { register } from "register-service-worker";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}firebase-messaging-sw.js`, {
    registered() {
      console.log("Service worker has been registered.");
    },
    cached() {
      console.log("Content has been cached for offline use.");
    },
    updatefound() {
      // new content clear cache so user gets the new version
      caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
        cacheNames.forEach(cacheName => {
          caches.delete(cacheName);
        });
      });
      console.log("New content is downloading.");
    },
    updated() {
      console.log("New content is available; please refresh.");
    },
    offline() {
      console.log(
        "No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode."
      );
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error("Error during service worker registration:", error);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I think it works but I need to test it with some clients. Thanks!